# Sending email in contact page not working

Tags: email, html-email, php

I am using following code, copied from a website, for a contact page. But I am not getting any emails and the attached files don't find their way to my webserver folder /var/www/. Am I missing something here?

I am running this code on localhost.

**email.php**

```
ob_start();

$to = 'baltusaj@gmail.com';

/*$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$confirm_email = $_POST['confirm_email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$hidden = $_POST['hidden'];
$from = $email;
*/
$keys = array('name', 'email', 'confirm_email', 'subject', 'comments', 'hidden');
foreach($keys as $key)
{
    $$key = isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null ;
} 

print ('
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
       <title>Email</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
function progress(){
intWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("container1").style.width) + 1;
if(intWidth <= 400){
     document.getElementById("container1").style.width = intWidth+"px";
}else{
     document.getElementById("container1").style.width = 0;
}
     setTimeout("progress()",300);
}
/*]]>*/
</script>
</head>

<body>
');

//Make sure email and confirm email are the same
if (!empty ($hidden)) {
    if ($email == $confirm_email) {
    }else{
    $email = '';
    $confirm_email = '';
    }
}


//Do a reg_ex check on the email
if (!empty ($hidden)) {    
   $regexp = "^([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$";
   if (eregi($regexp, $email))
   {
   }else{
       $email = '';
    $confirm_email = '';
   }
}
// End of email checking




if (empty ($hidden)) {

print ('<div id="container2">
<h1 id="content_h1"><a name="text">    E-mail </a></h1> <p>Please use the following form to e-mail us:</p>

');

include ("form.php");    

print ('</div>

<div id="container0" style="display: none;">

<p style="font-size: 15pt; font-family: sans-serif; color:#fd6700; background:#fff;">
    Loading...
    </p>

<div id="container1" style="width:0px; height:5px; background-color:#fd6700; margin-top:0px; text-align: left;"></div>

<p>Please be patient while your data is processed. This may take a few moments especially if you are uploading a file.</p>

</div>
');

}

if (!empty ($hidden)) {

    if ($_FILES['fileatt']['error'] == 1){
        print ('<h1 id="content_h1"><a name="text">There has been an error</a></h1>  
                <p>The maximum file size that can be uploaded using this form is 2 megabytes.
                </p>');

    }elseif ( (!empty ($name)) && (!empty ($email)) && (!empty ($comments))&& (!empty ($subject))) {

    // Get html message content
$form_data = "<p>This email is from <span class=\"bold\">$name</span> \n\n ";
$form_data .= "<p>$comments</p>";

$message =         "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \n" .
                "    \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\"> \n" .
                "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> \n" .
                "<head> \n" .
                "  <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content= \n" .
                "  \"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\" /> \n" .
                "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n" .
                "body {    font-size: 9pt; font-family:  verdana, sans-serif;     color: #000; background:#fff; }  \n" .
                ".bold { font-weight: bold; }  \n" .
                "</style>  \n" .
                "</head> \n" .
                "<body>$form_data \n" .
                "</body> \n" .
                "</html> \n\n";

// Obtain file upload vars
$fileatt      = $_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'];
$fileatt_type = $_FILES['fileatt']['type'];
$fileatt_name = $_FILES['fileatt']['name'];


$headers = "From: $from";

if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
// Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

// Generate a boundary string
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

// Add the headers for a file attachment
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
             "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
             " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

// Add a multipart boundary above the html message
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
            $message . "\n\n";


// Base64 encode the file data
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

//We now have everything we need to write the portion of the message that contains the file attachment. Here's the code:

// Add file attachment to the message
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
             "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
             " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
             "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
             " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
             $data . "\n\n" .
             "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
}else{
     // Generate a boundary string
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

// Add the headers for a file attachment
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
             "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
             " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

// Add a multipart boundary above the html message
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
            $message . "\n\n";
}                        


//That completes the modifications necessary to accommodate a file attachment. We can now send the message with a quick call to mail:

// Send the message
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$body = "Dear $name, \n\nThank you for your email. We will contact you as soon as possible regarding the matter. \n \n";

mail ($email, "Re: $subject", $body, 'From:you@your_email.com');

print ('<h1 id="content_h1"><a name="text">            Thank you             </a></h1> <p>We will contact you as soon as possible. You will receive an automatic e-mail immediately confirming the reception of your email.</p>');

}else{
    print ('<h1 id="content_h1"><a name="text">There has been an error</a></h1>  <p>Please fill in all the compulsory fields correctly and then resubmit the form. Thank you.</p>');
    include ("form.php");    
}
}

// This is the end of the insert

print ('

  </div>
</body>
</html>
');

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

**form.php**

```
<div id="form">
        <form  action="email.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="
        document.getElementById('container0').style.display='';
        document.getElementById('container2').style.display='none';
        progress();
        return true;">
        <fieldset id="fieldset">
        <label for="name">Contact name<span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
        <input <?php if (!empty ($hidden)) { if (empty ($name)) { print 'style="background: pink;"'; } } ?> class="form_elements" id="name" type="text" name="name" value="<?php print "$name"; ?>" tabindex="1" />
        <br />
        <label for="email">E-mail address<span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
        <input <?php if (!empty ($hidden)) { if (empty ($email)) { print 'style="background: pink;"'; } } ?> class="form_elements" id="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php print "$email"; ?>" tabindex="1" />
        <br />    
        <label for="confirm_email">Confirm e-mail<span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
        <input <?php if (!empty ($hidden)) { if (empty ($confirm_email)) { print 'style="background: pink;"'; } } ?> class="form_elements" id="confirm_email" type="text" name="confirm_email" value="<?php print "$confirm_email"; ?>" tabindex="1" />
        <br />    
        <label for="subject">Subject<span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
        <input <?php if (!empty ($hidden)) { if (empty ($subject)) { print 'style="background: pink;"'; } } ?> class="form_elements" id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value="<?php print "$subject"; ?>" tabindex="1" />
        <br />    
        <label for="comments">Comments<span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
        <textarea <?php if (!empty ($hidden)) { if (empty ($comments)) { print 'style="background: pink;"'; } } ?>class="form_elements" id="comments" name="comments" cols="19" rows="5" tabindex="1"><?php print "$comments"; ?></textarea>
        <br /><br />
        <label for="fileatt">Attach document:</label>
        <input id="fileatt" type="file" name="fileatt"  tabindex="1" />
        <br />
        <input  type="hidden" name="hidden"  value="1" /><br />
        <label for="submit"><span style="color: red;">*</span> Compulsory fields.</label>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="1" />
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the kajillionth time on this site: Don't build your own mime messages, it's unreliable and painful. Use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) instead. PHP's mail() function is highly unreliable and cannot produce ANY useful diagnostics as to why things are failing. Swift/PHPMailer will both tell you exactly why something blew up.

beyond that, nowhere do you seem to be doing a `move_uploaded_file()`, so your uploaded files will be auto-deleted by PHP when the script exits. You MUST deal with the files yourself, which means you have to write code to move the files to whatever place you want them stored in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running an SMTP server on your localhost?